# Заполнить вектор с заданным размером с помощью std::push_back(value);

Tags: c++

Есть вектор с заданным размером:

```
const int N=5;
vector<int>a(N);
```

Заполняю вектор методом push_back;

```
for (int i=0;i<N;++i)
{
    a.push_back(i+2);
}
for (int i:a)
{
    cout<<i<<" ";
}
```

Выводит N нулей, и сами элементы:
0 0 0 0 0 2 3 4 5 6
Как избавиться от нулей?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот этим:

```
vector<int>a(N);
```

вы создаете вектор, изначально заполненный `N` нулевыми элементами. Замените строку на

```
vector<int>a;
```

и все получится :)

Answer (score 1):

Вы заполняете вектор дважды. Сначала конструктор создает `N` элементов, а потом вы добавляете в цикле еще `N` элементов. Имеет смысл создать пустой вектор, зарезервировав место под все элементы.

```
::std::size_t const items_count{5};
::std::vector<int> items{};
a.reserve(items_count);
::std::size_t item_index{};
for
(
    item_index = ::std::size_t{0};
    items_count != item_index;
    ++item_index
)
{
    items.emplace_back(static_cast<int>(item_index + ::std::size_t{2}));
}
```